# Regex for a field not equal to zero

Tags: validation, regex-negation

I want to add a validation to input field so that it won't accept zero as valid input. I want to use a regex for that, so it allows everything except zero.

I tested a couple of regex e.g. `^((?!0).)*$` but did not quite get the thing that I was looking for.

Comment: do you can better explanation of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with  .*(?!0)

? Normally this should work, as . matches any character excepted new line.
Don't forget to add the flag g when you use your regexp, otherwise, it will stop after first matching.
Your final regexp should then be : /.*(?!0)/g